# Is it possible to Base Activity background on it's child Activity

Tags: java, android

**ParentActivity**

I want to play video in base Activity so each it's child have to play seamless video in each activity

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.splash);


  }
}
```

**Child Activity**

```
 public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.splash);


}
}
```

Comment: Instead of multiple activities, you can achieve this functionality with multiple fragments

Comment: Yes I can do this, but it is possible ?

Comment: Yes. Of course, add multiple fragments and add/remove then into/from the container. And let activity play the video

Comment: with Activities Only I have big code but client requirement show video in each place seamless, so in short time I need to change Activity to fragment and call ,backstack etc. So I ask this because I am doing like this

Comment: If you wanted to do it that way then you need to have a VideoView in every activity. Is it easy enough??

Comment: yes in each Activity but Video not playing seamless, when it stops in last activity

Comment: Yes, there should be some conflict which may take upto 500ms. but this won't happen in the case of Fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it, it depends what and how you want to achieve it, there're lot of ways to display a video.

Easier way is to create in the `BaseActivity` a `MediaPlayer` object as follows :

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(your_path_to_file);
    mp.prepare();
  }
}
```

And then from the childs you can use `mp.start();` to start the video.

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.splash);
      mp.start()
  }
}
```

Comment: But the View of Baseclass come on it's a child ?

Comment: this is good for playing mp3 but I want play Video from Base Activity which seemless play in all it's child activity

Comment: I can do by this by @Rahul Khurana comment but more activity needs to change fragment and back stack Also...

Comment: if I am giving layout to BaseActivity which is showing in top of LoginActivity Layout

Answer (score 0):

You can put video playing code in base activity, then your every activity which extends the base activity can just call the parent class's function to play video. SIMPLE